# Serialise / deserialise model in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, serialization, deserialization, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following class that I want to store in firestore.

```
public class User extends Model {

    @PropertyName("user_auth_id")
    public String authUid;

    @PropertyName("first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @PropertyName("last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @PropertyName("picture_url")
    public String pictureUrl;

    @PropertyName("email")
    public String email;

    @PropertyName("companies")
    public ArrayList<UserCompany> companies;

    public User() {}
}

public class UserCompany extends Model {

public String name;
public String role;
public String position;

public UserCompany() {
    super();
}

public UserCompany(Company company, String role, String position) {
    this();
    name = company.name;
    this.role = role;
    this.position = position;
}

public Map<String, Object> toObject() {
    Map<String, Object> object = new HashMap<>();
    object.put("id", id);
    object.put("name", name);
    object.put("role", role);
    object.put("position", position);
    return object;
}
}

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Model {
@Exclude
public String id;

public <T extends Model> T withId(@NonNull final String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return (T) this;
}
}
```

And I want to use a transaction to update an user entry with it's newly created company list. (appUser instanceOf User)

```
transaction.update(userRef, "companies", appUser.companies);
```

If I do so...I get

> Invalid data. Unsupported type: ro.exemple.model.UserCompany

How can I serialise an User object so that I can deserialise it as such

```
User appUser = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).toObject(User.class);
```

Where queryDocumentSnapshots is the result of a query in my firestore db.

I know I can change from ArrayList to HashMap, but I wish to keep the List, and try to serialise and deserialise it, in order to obtain in firestore an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

if this serialization you must tag your class as Serializable..

```
public UserCompany extends Model implements Serializable
public class User extends Model implements Serializable
```

plus tag the class `Model` as well

Comment: Tried it mate, it doesn't solve my issue. When trying to call transaction.update, the appUser.companies causes an exception. Something regarding UserCompany and it being incompatible.

Comment: The Serializable interface isn't necessary for Firestore serialization.  It doesn't work at all like Java platform serialization.